# PHP IF Else Help Required

Tags: php, if-statement

I have been going mad, ive read and tried everything i can find, im hoping someone will be able to help me complete..

```
if ($reportData['refund_amount_ex'] > $reportData['returned_products_cost_amount'] = $reportData['profit'] = + $reportData['profit']);

else $reportData['profit'] = - $reportData['profit'];
```

The if should be, if refund amount is greater than products cost it should =

Currently we only see the else

Thank you very much in advance
Thanks
Russell

Comment: This is unicornphp. You better read some tutorials on how PHP works.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `if` and `else` are meant for... what does `= +` even mean?

Comment: Read about `AND [&&]` | `OR [||]` statements in conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only quickly looked but you should check out [W3 tutorial on if, else, elseif](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp)

```
if ($reportData['refund_amount_ex'] > $reportData['returned_products_cost_amount']){ 
$reportData['profit'] =+ $reportData['profit'];
}

else { 
$reportData['profit'] =- $reportData['profit'];
}
```

Comment: it would be better to link to the php manual for [`if`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) / [`else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) / [`elseif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), then W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you

```
if ($reportData['refund_amount_ex'] > $reportData['returned_products_cost_amount'])
       $reportData['profit'] =+ $reportData['profit'];
 else 
    $reportData['profit'] =- $reportData['profit'];
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants `+=` is different than `=+` and you also have a `)` after `['profit']` which will cause an error to occur...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you mean to do I believe...

```
if ($reportData['refund_amount_ex'] > $reportData['returned_products_cost_amount']){
    $reportData['profit'] =+ $reportData['profit'];
}else{ 
    $reportData['profit'] =- $reportData['profit'];
}
```